# Problem with C++ class instance not being recognized

Tags: c++, c++11

This is for "homework" but this is not an algorithm question, but rather a programming issue.  As part of a project for my Data Structures class, I have to write a class to act as a database.  That part is done.  I am not asking about the algorithm, but rather, trying to isolate what is clearly a stupid bug on my part.

PeopleDB has two constructors, the default one and one that takes as a parameter an input file and reads it into the database to initialize it.

Here is the code snippet, the problem is described below it:

```
#include "People.h" // People class definition
#include "PeopleDB.h" // People database class
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Define variables
    string infilename;
    PeopleDB mydb;

    // Get the filename of the text file to process
    infilename = argv[1];

    // Try to open import the data into a database instance
    try
    {
        cout << "Attempting to import DB entries from "<< infilename << endl;
        PeopleDB mydb(infilename);
        cout << "# A total of "<< mydb.countEntries() << " DB entries loaded." << endl;
    }
    catch(PrecondViolatedExcep e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        cout << "Exiting program.";
        exit(1);
    }

    // Display database contents
    cout << endl;
    cout << "# A total of "<< mydb.countEntries() << " DB entries found before display." << endl;

    return 0;
}  // end main
```

The problem is if I don't include the *PeopleDB mydb;* constructor at the top of the main() loop, the compiler barfs saying it doesn't recognize the *mydb.countEntries()* in the second to last line of the main loop.  But if I do include it, it is clear that the mydb within the try loop doesn't survive because the output of the program is:

```
Attempting to import DB entries from testinput.txt
# A total of 7 DB entries loaded.

# A total of 0 DB entries loaded.
```

I didn't want to use the same variable (*mydb*) twice (I actually assumed this would error out during compiling), but for some reason creating the *mydb* instance of *PeopleDB* inside the try block doesn't seem to survive to be outside the block.  I am sure this is something stupid on my part, but I am not seeing it.  It has been a long day, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you put the whole code in the try block, you would not need 2 variables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare two independent `mydb` objects.

Either perform all actions in the try-catch block, or move connecting to another function.

```
PeopleDB connect(const std::string& infilename) {
    try
    {
        cout << "Attempting to import DB entries from "<< infilename << endl;
        PeopleDB mydb(infilename);
        cout << "# A total of "<< mydb.countEntries() << " DB entries loaded." << endl;
        return mydb;
    }
    catch(PrecondViolatedExcep e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        cout << "Exiting program.";
        exit(1);
    }
    return PeopleDB{};
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Get the filename of the text file to process
    string infilename = argv[1];
    PeopleDB mydb = connect(infilename);

    // Display database contents
    cout << endl;
    cout << "# A total of "<< mydb.countEntries() << " DB entries found before display." << endl;

    return 0;
}  // end main
```

Comment: Thank you!  This would work except I didn't have a copy constructor. But I think I can build that.  Thanks!

Comment: If you use C++14, no copy constructor is needed.

Comment: Yeah, it worked!  Thank you for the help.  I did use your code and properly credited you in my copy of it.  This really did help!

Answer (score 3):

You are creating two objects `myDb` of type `PeopleDB`: one at the beginning of main, the other one in the `try` block. That latter one loads the data, but gets gets destroyed with the end of that try block's scope.
The second one being printed is the one created in the main block, and that one has never loaded the data.

There are multiple ways to fix that, e.g. provide a method to load data and call it inside the `try` block. Another option is to copy/move/swap the "inside" one with the "outside" one before the `try` block ends (but I'd provide different names in such case). Your call, but bottom line is: at that point you have two different objects: one the data is loaded to, and the other one it is printed from (with empty results).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I *knew* using two *mydb* shouldn't work, but I couldn't figure out why my declaration of mydb inside the try block was being ignored. 

I get it now, any variable/instance declared in the brackets will be disposed of when exiting the code within the brackets.  That makes sense.  Thanks for the clarification of the error on my part!

Answer (score 0):

Try using move-assignment inside the *try* block:

```
mydb = std::move(PeopleDB(infilename));
```

The reason why I suggested this, is because it avoids creating a new object inside the try block because this object will disappear after the scope of the try block ends.

The reason for using `move` is to prevent creating the object twice:

- once with the constructor call
- another with the copy-constructor call

However, now I realize that the `std::move` is redundant because `PeopleDB(infilename)` is already an rvalue reference, and compiler will be smart enough to do the move itself.

So my new suggestion is to just do:

```
mydb = PeopleDB(infilename);
```

Comment: Can you clarify **why** this will help?

Comment: @JEC You don't provide needed definition and when someone make a guess you complain.

Comment: Moving is absolutely unnecessary there.

Comment: @Phil1970. Sorry.  Let me try to clarify, I want to specifically understand what the move command does.  The documentation suggests it allows the object I create with PeopleDB(infilename) to be assigned to mydb (which is declared outside the try block).  

I didn't post the PeopleDB definition because this is a homework problem and I don't want to post something others could use to actually figure out the algorithms we need for the class.

Comment: @JEC see explanation.

Comment: @smac89 Thank you for the expanded clarification!  Makes a lot more sense now!  Thanks for making the effort to explain it to a relative newbie at C++.